# Authentication in Oracle Apex app using Active Directory

Tags: authentication, active-directory, oracle-apex

I am currently working on an Oracle Apex(v21.1) project. I would like the users to authenticate based on their login informations of the Windows Active Directory of my company. This could help me to filter some report based on the user's group.

I don't understand much about the way to link an active directory with oracle apex, so that's why I am looking for someone with much more knowledge than me that could lead me to the right path.

I've already made some research on the subject, I've came across some topics talking about the Authentication Schema using LDAP Directory, but I'm not sure if this is the thing i'm looking for.

If you guys could help me or lead me to a detailed tutorial, i would be very grateful

Thank you in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try test ldap login?

[image]

I'm assuming you know your a/d host ip, port, DN String

If you enter these correctly, Test should success and you can mark it as "Current".

Comment: Hello Oguen, I haven't tried these yet because i'm not the administrator on the IT and i don't have the informations to connect to it, I just wanted to make sure that the LDAP Directory Authentication was the right thing before going on. Now that I have the confirmation, i will be abl to continue. Thank your for your help !